# Recharts How to group by series?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time-series, recharts

See Codepen: [Rechart Series Data Chart](https://codepen.io/michael-griffith/pen/OrMNBe)

[image: Existing Chart]

See the series for events (labs, notes, etc) causing a duplicate key on my XAxis. I want the Note and Lab events to show on the same date. Also the event should be horizontally aligned with the events yAxis. While they are roughly aligned the data point is too far above the intersection of where I thought it would be.

Screen shot shows desired position

[image: Desired chart]

Codepen.io code:

```
 const {CartesianGrid,
    Legend,
    Line,
    LineChart,
    LabelList,   
    BarChart,
    Bar,   
    ReferenceDot,
    ResponsiveContainer,
    CartesianAxis,   
    ComposedChart,   
    Scatter,
    Tooltip,
    Cross,  
    XAxis,
    YAxis} = Recharts;

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const data = [
            {name: '5/7/18', pain: 5, temp: 98.6, pulse: 77, event: 'Notes'},
            {name: '5/7/18', pain: 5, temp: 98.6, pulse: 77, event: 'Lab'},
            {name: '5/8/18', pain: 5, temp: 98.8, pulse: 90, event: 'Tx'},
            {name: '5/9/18', pain: 7, temp: 99.5, pulse: 100, event: 'Lab' },
            {name: '5/10/18', pain: 8, temp: 100.6, pulse: 103, event: 'Vitals'},
            {name: '5/11/18', pain: 7, temp: 99.8, pulse: 90, event: 'Notes'},
            {name: '5/12/18', pain: 5, temp: 98.6, pulse: 80, event: 'Tx'},
        ];
   const scatterData= [{name:'Lab'},
                       {name:'Notes'}]

        return (
            <div>
                <ResponsiveContainer width="90%" height={460}>

                    <ComposedChart data={data}>
                        <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
                        <YAxis yAxisId='left'  domain={[0,140]} label={{value: 'Vitals', angle: 0, position: 'insideBottomLeft'}}/>
                        <YAxis yAxisId='events' type='category'   padding={{ top: 20 }} />
                        <YAxis yAxisId="right" domain={[0,10]} orientation="right" label={{value: 'Pain', angle: 90, position: 'outsideRight'}} />
                        <CartesianGrid vertical={true} strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
                        <Tooltip/>
                        <Legend/>
                        <Line type="monotone" yAxisId='right' dataKey="pain" stroke="#82ca9d" activeDot={{r: 4}}/>
                        <Line type="monotone" yAxisId='left' dataKey="temp" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 6}}/>
                        <Line type="monotone" yAxisId='left' dataKey="pulse" stroke="blue" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
                        <Bar yAxisId='events' layout='verticle' barSize={0} maxBarSize={0} fill='#413ea0'  dataKey='event'>
                          <LabelList dataKey="event" content={renderCustomizedLabel} />
                        </Bar>
                    </ComposedChart>
                </ResponsiveContainer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const renderCustomizedLabel = (props) => {
  const { x, y, width, height, value } = props;
  const radius = 14;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
  return (
          <g>
                <circle cx={x + width / 2} cy={y - radius} r={radius} fill="#8884d8" />
                <text x={x + width / 2} y={y - radius} fill="#fff" textAnchor="middle" dominantBaseline="middle">
                    {value[0]}
                </text>
            </g>  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('main'));
```